# how to display a modal “Loading…” message in xamarin.form iOS platform

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a tab base app in which each tab have a CotntentPage . For some long running tasks I want to display modal popup loading message.

For android, I am able to do through ProgressDialog but in iOS I am not getting any way to do it.

I have tried the sample from https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/ but got stuck at below line

```
var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

// show the loading overlay on the UI thread using the correct orientation sizing
loadPop = new LoadingOverlay (bounds); // using field from step 2
View.Add (loadPop);
```

I am not getting the View property .

Comment: There are numerous ways to achieve this, any thoughts on the type of loading message you'd like? I.E. an example of what your trying to replicate in iOS.

Comment: what is the context in which you're writing this code?  A View?  A ViewController?  Or what?